# Orchestration processes the data, but incorrectly, sends message to receive folder and invalid folder. MS Biztalk tutorial

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I am doing this tutorial from Microsoft Biztalk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/tutorial-1-enterprise-application-integration.

I process the file and it does not error, but it does not get processed correctly. It ends up in both folders, invalid and valid. It looks as though it is not hitting the decide shape.

[image: Orchestration Image].

Anyone else run across this? I'm using BizTalk 2020 and Visual Studio 2019, running as administrator.

Comment: Have you tried the Orchestration debugger to see which shapes it goes through?   Is the Orchestration bound to the send ports, or are you using filters on the send ports?

Comment: Also did you restart the host instances after making changes and re-deploying?

Comment: I haven't been able to get the Orchestration debugger to come up on my box. Yes I restart the host instances after every deploy. You set the filters after binding the ports to the orchestration. if you don't you get a no subscriber error.

Comment: So what filters are you using on the send ports?  Add those to the question

Comment: BTS.ReceivePortName is the only filters I'm using.

Comment: Well then it isn't even coming from the Orchestrations, but directly from the Receive Port to the Send Ports and bypassing the Orchestration.  Do you even see an instance of the Orchestration in the Tracked Service Instances in the BizTalk Admin Console?

Comment: Did my answer below help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues here

1. Your filter on the Send Ports using `BTS.ReceivePortName`, means that the send ports are directly subscribing to the Receive Port and not going through the Orchestration.  You either need to set the send shapes in the Orchestration to Specify Later, and  then Bind the Orchestration to the send port in the BizTalk Admin Console/Bindings.  Or you need to set a filter on the send port to subscribe to promoted properties in the message.  Note:  You need to make sure that the promoted property you use is not in the message your receive port puts in the message box.  Easiest is BTS.Operation = {NameOfOperationInOrchSendPortShape}
2. The fact that you can't debug the Orchestration, indicates to me that the Orchestration didn't even run.  So either the subscription that the Orchestration has is wrong.  You can check this in the BizTalk Admin console by searching for Subscriptions, or by checking what message type you have on your receive shape in your Orchestration or if you have any additional filters.  Or the message doesn't have the context properties you expect.  Usually this is due to either not using a Disassembler in the receive pipeline, or the namespace doesn't match.

Comment: 1. So do the Send Ports need to subscribe to the Orchestration?

Comment: @jamestreinen Added details to answer that

Comment: @jamestreinen  Did my answer resolve your problems?